# (Ubuntu 16.04 Server) systemd update lightdm.service from ansible

Tags: vpn, ansible, lightdm

I am making an ansible script to add an extra service (VPN/Strongswan) to be loaded to lightdm.service before booting to graphical.target / graphical GUI.

I am adding "strongswan.service" to the end of the "After=" list.

When I do this by hand, by editing `/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service` and then running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` it works correctly. The boot process goes from the service loading to the user login waits for strongswan and loads the GUI.

When I try to do this from ansible, the task fails to load in the user login. Does it need anything like `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to kick in?

Comment: Did you check the service file afterwards to make sure the changes `ansible` makes are correct?

Comment: You should not be editing files in `/lib/systemd/system/`. Use `systemctl edit` or override files in `/etc/systemd/system`. At any rate, you shouldn't have to edit lightdm.service anyway. Dependencies and order can be specified in the other service using WantedBy, Before, etc.

Comment: Problem is that lightdm.service runs a "kiosk" mode application so the first thing that it checks is to have proper network connection to replicate data locally. Since now this is on vpn it needs the vpn device to be loaded (thru strongswan) hence my editing of lightdm. From lightdm forth everything is being ran by a script.

Comment: override files in /etc/systemd/system -> does it mean that if I copy /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service to /etc... will be overriden?